# SQL Injection Doesn't Sanitize But Doesn't Execute Commands

Tags: sql-injection, databases

I am currently doing a pentesting on a web application and focusing more on SQL Injection. This company I am pentesting have a functionality in which we are allowed to buy things from the vendors/suppliers registered there. When a product is added to our cart and 'Checkout' button is clicked, the web application will then communicate to the backend to create a cart based on specified 'cart_id' and INSERT it to the database. I know this is the case since when I tried to resubmit the request to the server the following error is specified:

```
"SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC_CART_ID' for key 'idx_cart_id'"
```

I tried checking for  SQL Injection by adding a single quote at the end of the 'cart_id' and HTTP 200 is returned along with server response of a new cart_id with the single quote included. Does this mean It is not sanitizing input? I tried inserting other SQL Commands, the server will still return 200 and the commands are being printed out on the server response but not being executed. Is this web app vulnerable to SQLi (blind?)? If not, Is it possible for me to achieve other vuln such as Stored XSS?

Thank you

Comment: Update: I tried submitting a transaction with a SQLi payload in as the 'cart_id' and it went through, but when I tried going to my history of purchase and view the order, I received a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: If it was vulnerable, your first request would have failed instead of returning the `cart_id` with single quote.
You should try having a `cart_id` with two singles quotes `''`. If the returned cart_id has two single quotes in it, it is most likely safe from injections. If it has none, it is most likely injectable.

Comment: @Xavier59, Thank you for the reply. So almost all SQLi is tested using the single quote? What is confusing me is that when I tried to access the transaction history it returns an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error which usually translate to SQLi right?